# Bootstrap 3 обтекание

Tags: bootstrap

[image: ведите сюда описание изображения]

Как Block 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 разместить как на картинке справа? Структура разметки:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
            Block 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
            Menu accordion
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">    
    Block 3 
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">    
        Block 4 
            </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">    
        Block 5 
            </div>  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">    
        Block 6 
    </div>  
    </div></div>
```

Comment: А Вам надо, чтобы и пропорции блоков сохранялись как на картинке? Типа Block1 - маленький, Block3 - самый большой, Block4 и Block5 - поменьше. Или главное - сам принцип: чтобы меню и Block6 показывались слева?

Comment: Сам принцип важен. Сверстать под большие мониторы так можно, есть рабочий вариант. А вот сверстать от маленьких до больших не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое - это скрывать и открывать меню и блок 6 на разных экранах:

```css
.col-xs-12,
.col-sm-9,
.col-sm-3 {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
.col-sm-9,
.col-sm-3 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                Menu accordion
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">    
                Block 6 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                Block 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
                Menu accordion
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">    
                Block 3 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">    
                Block 4 
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-12">    
                Block 5 
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">    
                Block 6 
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как поисковики отнесутся по сути к дублям Block 6 и Menu accordion ?

Comment: @ikar, а почему поисковики это должно смущать? код валидный

Comment: Block 6 - это новости с ссылкой на полную версию. И на странице будет дубль заголовка и краткого описания, вот что получится.

Comment: @ikar, я знаю, что на разных страницах одного сайта не должно быть дублирующегося контента. про одну и ту же страницу ничего не слышал

Comment: Если решать этот же вопрос с помощью JavaScript, то как определить когда надо добавлять узлы в DOM при экранах XS, SM, MD, LG?

Comment: @ikar, можно с помощью проверки if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches). проводить её надо не только при загрузке страницы, но и по событию изменения размера окна window.resize

Comment: @ikar, брейкпоинты, соответственно: xs - 767px, sm - 991px, md - 1199px

Comment: @ikar, но я бы не советовал Вам использовать js, потому что если у кого-то он отключен или просто долго загружается, Ваша вёрстка превратится в фарш :(

Comment: скрипт JS может проверить включён или отключен JS в браузере у пользователя?

Comment: @ikar, может :)

Comment: и всё же надо использовать JS. Если есть два блока которые одинаковые и у них есть id="", то скрытие/показ средствами CSS не годится.

Comment: @ikar, почему не годится? как связаны id и скрытие/показ средствами CSS?

Comment: если мы используем CSS, то в HTML- структуре страницы будет два одинаковых блока с одинаковыми ID (допустим эти блоки, - блоки-меню). У меня есть вызов для меню jQuery('#menu').accordionMenu().show(); Соответственно вызов срабатывает только для первого блока кода в структуре HTML. Задача - скрытие/показ одного и того же блока в разных местах при разном разрешении экрана, средствами CSS не всегда можно решить.

Comment: @ikar, блоков с одинаковым id быть не может - это ГРУБЕЙШАЯ ошибка. Почитайте про азы вёрстки: что такое id, зачем он нужен и т.д.

Comment: это мне известно. Но не переделывать ведь теперь сложное accordion-меню написанное на jquery. Поэтому и написал "средствами CSS не всегда можно решить".

Comment: @ikar, в смысле - "не переделывать"? у Вас код невалидный :))) разумеется, переделывать

Comment: два одинаковых блока навигации в структуре HTML, даже с разными ID, не лучшая практика для решения такого рода задач. Вы по видимому путаете суть моей задачи, "скрытие/показ одного и того же блока в РАЗНЫХ МЕСТАХ при разном разрешении экрана", с тем когда требуется скрыть/показать блок при маленьком/большом разрешении экрана (решается в Bootstrap, так hidden-xs, visible-lg).